# Laravel AJAX Form loses values on submit validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I everybody! 
In my page I have a select element that gives the option to fill an determied form, it fills with the update of `@include('pergunta.pergunta')`.
This is the form:

```
@if ($errors->has())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ HTML::ul($errors->all()) }}
    </div>
@endif
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'AController@store','id'=>'formA')) }}
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                {{ Form::label('modelo', 'Modelo') }}
                {{-- MY SELECT ELEMENT --}}
                <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('modelo')) has-error @endif">
                    <select id="sModelo" name="modelo" class="form-control" style= "width: 150px">
                        <option value="" disabled selected> Modelo </option>
                        @foreach ($modelos as $modelo)
                            <option value="{{$modelo->id }}">  {{$modelo->nome }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>    
        </tbody>
    </table>
        ...
        <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('user')) has-error @endif">
            <select class="form-control" name="user">
                <option value="" disabled selected>User</option>
                @foreach ($users as $key => $value)
                    <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{ $value->nome }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        ...
        <select class="form-control" name="user2">
            <option value="" disabled selected>User2</option>
            @foreach ($user2 as $key => $value)
                <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{ $value->nome }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        {{ Form::label('', Auth::user()->nome ,array('class' => 'labels')) }}
        <!-- Descriçao da Situação -->
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed alinhar">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="titulo" style="width:250px;">Descriçao</td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="form-group @if ($errors->has('situacao')) has-error @endif">
                        {{ Form::textarea('situacao', null, ['placeholder' => 'Descrição da Situação', 'class' => 'form-control','size' => '30x1']) }}
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        --> THIS IS WHAT IS GOING TO BE UPDATED
        <!-- Blocos Perguntas -->
        <table id="updateTable" class="table table-bordered table-condensed alinhar">
            @include('pergunta.pergunta')
        </table>
```

My function of AJAX is in a js file:

```
    $("#sModelo").on('change', function(e){
        var idModelo = e.target.value;
        $('#updateTable').load('/admin/a/pesquisa/' + idModelo);
    });
```

My Controller:

```
public function store()
{
    if (!$this->audit->isValid(Input::all())) {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->audit->errors);
    }
    ...
    return Redirect::action('AController@index');
}
```

What happens is that every time i submit the form and i have fields that are not filled or are incorrect in the main page, i get the notification in the page by laravel serve, but i lose my page that was submit by ajax and all the values that were fill. How can i do the client validation of text box's and select elements without first going to the server and validate?

Comment: Your asking how to do client side verification ? if so then js is your answer there are bunch of plugins witch will simplify the process for you. btw you can keep the values if you would use `Input::old` in the value

Comment: I use Input::old my problem is "losing the page" that was submited by ajax.